# Loopback hasMany relation doesn't work on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have some strange behavior after moving from RedHat linux to SUSE on AWS.

Everything was working fine, before.

Here is my relations:

Category:

```
{
    "name": "Category",
    "plural": "categories",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "relations": {
      ...
      "professions": {
        "type": "hasMany",
        "model": "Profession",
        "foreignKey": ""
      }
    }
 }
```

Profession:

```
{
    "name": "Profession",
    "plural": "professions",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "relations": {
      ...
      "category": {
        "type": "belongsTo",
        "model": "Category",
        "foreignKey": ""
      }
    }
 }
```

The problem is that when I update an existing profession with:

```
{
     "categoryId" : "..."
}
```

It doesn't work when I request /api/categories/{id}/professions

But /api/profession/{id}/category works fine.

Also if I create new Profession like:

```
{
     "name" : "TEST",
     "categoryId" : "..."
}
```

It works fine both ways.

Category.professions.create({ name: "TEST2" }); Works fine as well.

I was using RedHat linux on AWS. Now I am using SUSE linux on AWS.

Mongo db version : db version v3.0.7

EDIT:

```
node --version
v5.4.1

npm --version
3.3.12

npm list loopback
`-- loopback@2.26.2
```

EDIT:

I tried to update it from /explorer panel and code.

in code (angular) I do this:

```
Profession.prototype$updateAttributes(
{
    id: toAdd[i]
},
{
    categoryId: catId
});
```

And as I said, all the code works on test server running RDHE.
I will check mongo logs, but I installed the same mongo version and using same mongo.config

Comment: May or may not be related - your Profession model has a typo in the plural property, "proffesions". This should influence the URL (making it /api/proffesions).

Comment: Sorry that's only a typo in the post...

Comment: How are you updating the profession entity? Through an API endpoint or in code? Please update the question here to make it clear how you are doing the update! Just as a note though, switching from one linux distro to another shouldn't matter. I'd be sure to check the mongo logs!

Comment: jakerella:
I updated the question. Will include mongo logs ASAP

Comment: Mongo db log doesn't give anything as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey... so the problem was one or both of these modules:

```
"loopback-connector-mongodb": "^1.13.0"
"loopback-datasource-juggler": "^2.39.0"
```

Since the version number is written as ^#.#.# it means higher but compatible.
But one of them wasn't working: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/274

This caused all the problems.

Simple solution:

```
"loopback-connector-mongodb": "1.13.0"
"loopback-datasource-juggler": "2.39.0"
```

I just installed the versions which i know that works.