# Loopback "hasMany" relation issue in (PUT modelA/{id}/modelB/{fk}) method with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to use `(GET or PUT) /modelA/{id}/modelB/{fk}`, to add a relation from an existing model in A and B.

Every time, I use the method I just get:
`"No instance with id xxxxx found for modelB"` (Althought this instance already exist).

```
ModelA.json
{
 "name":"modelA",
  ...
  "relations": {
    "deals": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Deal",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  ....
}



ModelB.json
{
  "name":"modelB",
   ...
   "relations": {
    "category": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "modelA",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
    }
   ....
}
```

**Note:** Im using MongoDB. I tried the option here ([Loopback hasMany relation doesn't work on mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338292/loopback-hasmany-relation-doesnt-work-on-mongodb)) of changing the version of mongodb connector and juggler, but still the same.

Also, I have another model C (modelA hasMany model of it, relation defined in .json), but modelC (can also be in many, but not define in .json, just implicit, because I don't need the inverse relation), and also the method (PUT) and (GET) that have the fk are not working `(GET or PUT) /modelA/{id}/modelC/{fk}`.

Comment: I have the same problem. No solutions so far?